# Create makefile with MKMF

Tags: ruby, makefile, extconf.rb, mkmf

How can I create a sophisticated Makefile with MKMF?
I need to specify targets, include other makefiles, specify macros and so on. Is that possible?  I'm pretty new to MKMF and I only find very basic examples how to use MKMF on the web.

For example, I need the following line at the beginning of my Makefile:

```
-include ../../Makefile.local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research showed that MKMF is very limited in functionality. A better solution is to write a  makefile and include the necessary ruby headers and libraries. So in the end I didn't use MKMF at all.